# how to join vertices to form triangular mesh?

Tags: matlab, vertex

I have a set of triangulated mesh data. For every triangular face, I want to form a smaller similar triangle inside. I generated three new vertices for the new triangle in each original faces. How can I join all the three generated vertices in each faces using matlab?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertices in your triangulated mesh data will be placed in a list.

```
v[0] = (x0,y0,z0)
v[1] = (x1,y1,z1)
.
.
v[n] = (xn,yn,zn)
```

Next to this list, there will be a list of triangle or polygon data.

```
triangle[0] = (0,1,2)  // these are the indices of the vertex in the vertex list
triangle[1] = (1,2,3)
.
.
triangle[k] = ( , , )
```

If your new list of vertices has the same order as the original, you should be able to copy this list to a new mesh data object. If you now copy the same list of triangle or polygon data, your mesh should be created.